# Are there gotchas with creating an instance of a QQuickItem subclass which instance I don't intend to render or add to a QML tree?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickitem

As you know, a QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer subclass shouldn't access its parent item's properties directly, and instead should copy them to itself in its `synchronize()` method. So the code tends to look like this (using the `AUTO_PROPERTY` macro from [here](http://syncor.blogspot.bg/2014/11/qt-auto-property.html)):

```
class MyItem : public QQuickFramebufferObject {
    AUTO_PROPERTY(int, foo)
    AUTO_PROPERTY(float, bar)
    // ...
};

class MyItemRenderer : public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer {
public:
    void synchronize(QQuickFrameBufferObject* qqfbo) {
        auto src = (MyItem*)qqfbo;
        foo = src->foo();
        bar = src->bar();
    }
private:
    int foo;
    float bar;
    // ...
};
```

I wanted to avoid duplicating the declaration of properties between the two classes, so right now I'm implementing this alternative solution:

```
class MyItem : public QQuickFramebufferObject {
    AUTO_PROPERTY(int, foo)
    AUTO_PROPERTY(float, bar)
    // ...
};

class MyItemRenderer : public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer {
public:
    MyItemRenderer() {
        copiedData = new MyItem();
    }
    void synchronize(QQuickFrameBufferObject* qqfbo) {
        auto src = (MyItem*)qqfbo;
        copiedData.setFoo(src->foo());
        copiedData.setBar(src->bar());
    }
private:
    MyItem* copiedData;
};
```

I still need to write out and maintain the copying code as you see, but it's better than the other way.

**Are there gotchas with doing that? (creating an instance of a QQuickItem subclass which instance I don't intend to render or add to a QML tree)**.

Quote from the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html):

> This is useful for creating QML objects from C++ code, whether to display a QML object that can be visually rendered, or to integrate non-visual QML object data into a C++ application.

This seems to imply that such nonvisual usage is an intended and supported use case. But I'm not sure I'm reading it right.

Comment: Use `QtObject` for non-visual stuff, less overhead. The limitation is it can only have properties, not children, which is kinda silly, considering that it is essentially a `QObject` which can have children, the functionality is just not exposed to QML.

Comment: @ddriver: But the item I'm syncing *from* **is** a visual item, I can't make it a nonvisual item because then it wouldn't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to re-use a class for two purposes, better split the class into two and use aggregation.

```
class MyItem ....
{
    friend class MyItemRenderer;

private:
    Data m_data; // contains the property variables
};

class MyItemRenderer ...
{
public:
    void synchronize(QQuickFrameBufferObject* qqfbo) {
        auto myItem = static_cast<MyItem*>(qqfbo);
        m_data = myItem->m_data;
    }
private:
    Data m_data;
};
```